# How can we create nested arrays in scala from a dataframe?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with three columns; How can I convert it to a nested array in Scala - `Array[Array[Double]]`?

I am getting `Array[(Double, Double)]` when i try to map:

```
val x= dataframe.select("time","sex")
  .collect()
  .map(x=>x(0).toString.toDouble ,x(1).toString.toDouble)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your map is returning a tuple. since you needed an Array you need to return an Array as shown below.

```
val df = dataframe.collect().map(x => Array(x.getDouble(0), x.getDouble(1)))
```

to access the first item (nested Array) in the result use `df.head` or `df(0)`

**EDIT:**

to have the dataset in columnar fashion Array[Array[Double]] where the each column has its own array.

```
df.foldLeft((Array[Double](),Array[Double]())) {
  case ((col1,col2),(x,y)) => (col1 :+ x) -> (col2 :+ y)
} match {
    case (arr1,arr2) => Array(arr1,arr2)
}
```

Comment: How can we access first array from it?

Comment: @BejjamDEEPTHIPRIYA can you please elaborate your request?

Comment: From the above command we will getv array[array[double]] how can we access first array ???

Comment: Hi actually I'm looking for nestedarray[array[array1,array2]]  array 1 is one Column of dataframe and array 2 is another column and the solution u provided gives me arrays of each row .do u have any suggestion for my qstion if so please let me know

Comment: @Deep so you need Array[Array[Double],Array[Double]]. ie an Array with two arrays for each column (ie a column oriented storage)

Comment: Yeah ,that's what I need

Comment: ,can you elaborate the solution?

Comment: df is like a normal row based table. with two columns and multiple rows. now we will have to convert this to a table with a two columns but a single row. the single row will contain a seq of values for a given value. this process of converting values in multiple rows to a single row with sequence is accomplished by foldLeft method.

Comment: Hi I'm getting an error with the updated code at (x,y)

Comment: @Deep can you post the stacktrace?